# Query to count number of occurrence in array grouped by day

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document structure:

```
(trackerEventsCollection) = 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b26c4fb7c696201040c8ed1"),
        "trackerId" : ObjectId("598fc51324h51901043d76de"),
        "trackingEvents" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "checkin",
                "eventSource" : "app",
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-08-25T06:34:58.964Z")
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "power",
                "eventSource" : "app",
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-08-25T06:51:23.795Z")
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "position",
                "eventSource" : "app",
                "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-08-25T06:51:23.985Z")        
            }
        ]
    }
```

I would like to write a query that would count number of trackingEvents with type `"type" : "power"` grouped by day. This seems to be quite tricky to me because parent document does not have date and I should rely on `timestamp` field that belongs to the `trackingEvents` array members. 
I'm not really experienced mongodb user and couldn't understand how can this be achieved so far. 
Would really appreciate any help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process your nested array as a separate documents you need to use [$unwind.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) In the next stage you can use $match to filter out by `type`. Then you can group by single days counting occurences. The point is that you have to build grouping key containing year, month and day like in following code:

```
db.trackerEvents.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$trackingEvents" },
    { $match: { "trackingEvents.type": "power" } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                year: { $year:"$trackingEvents.timestamp" },
                month:{ $month:"$trackingEvents.timestamp" },
                day: { $dayOfMonth:"$trackingEvents.timestamp" }
            },
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```